# NPE in clojure.lang.Compiler when trying to load a resource

Tags: java, clojure

I already reported this problem in [CLJ-1172](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1172), but didn't receive any feedback from Clojure team. Maybe someone here can tell me what's wrong. This is my code:

```
import clojure.lang.Compiler;
Compiler.load(new StringReader("(+ 5 6)"));
```

Exception in runtime:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.<clinit>(Compiler.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at clojure.lang.RT.baseLoader(RT.java:2043)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
  at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:447)
  at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:329)
```

Looks like `RT` and `Compiler` classes statically refer to each other. I'm using `org.clojure:clojure:1.5.0` dependency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's OK for classes to statically refer to each other as long as their fields get initialized in the right order. In this case, Clojure probably expects `RT` to be initialized before `Compiler`. Here's the sequence of events:

1. When you make a static call to `Compiler`, Java initializes all the static fields in that class.
2. The static initializer for `Compiler.FNONCE` (line 47) calls a static method in `RT`, which causes that whole class to be initialized before the value of `FNONCE` is computed and set.
3. The static initializer block for `RT` that begins on line 299 calls a static method which eventually refers to the static `Compiler.LOADER` field.
4. The JVM would normally initialize the `Compiler` class here, but it sees that `Compiler` is currently being initialized and just grabs the current value. Fields are initialized in the order they are declared in the file, and since `LOADER` comes after `FNONCE` the un-initialized value of `null` is returned, throwing a NPE when it's dereferenced in `RT`.

Bottom line: make a call to some static method in `RT` (or read a static field) before your call to `Compiler.load` and your error should go away.

More details on the specifics of class initialization is available in section 12.4 of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4).

Comment: you're right, calling `RT.init()` beforehand solves the problem, thanks!